# Show that $\{ze^{z}:z\in \mathbb{C}\, \text{and}\, |z|>1\}$ contains $\{w\in \mathbb{C}: w\neq 0\}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that $\{ze^{z}:z\in \mathbb{C}\, \text{and}\, |z|>1\}$ contains $\{w\in \mathbb{C}: w\neq 0\}$.

I think that since the function $f(z)=ze^z$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$, for all $w\neq0$ except possibly one and for any $R>1$ there are infinitely many $z$ that $|z|>R$ and $f(z)=w$ by the Picard theorem but in the statement we should have for all $w\neq0$ so I am not sure about my solution. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $f$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$, in any neighbourhood of $\infty$, $f$ attains every value, except possibly one, infinitely often. In particular, as $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| > 1\}$ is a neighbourhood of $\infty$, $\{ze^z \mid |z| > 1\}$ is either $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{a\}$ for some $a$.

What you haven't justified in your argument is that if $\{ze^z \mid |z| > 1\} = \mathbb{C}\setminus\{a\}$, then $a$ must be zero. To see this, note that $ze^z = 0$ if and only if $z = 0$ (as $e^z \neq 0$ for any $z$). Therefore, $0 \not\in \{ze^z \mid |z| > 1\}$, so $\{ze^z \mid |z| > 1\} = \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The one value you don't have for $z \ne 0$ is $0$.  By Picard there can't be any others.